# Simplifying constant coefficient in a matrix

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, coefficients

I made this matrix and now I need to simplify it.in my matrix a,k,and Subscript[u, 10] could be simplified, I used Simplify function for them but it seems to does not apply on it.
this is my code :

```
a;
k;
Subscript[u, 10];
IndexedExpression[i_, j_] := 
 HoldForm[TraditionalForm[D[Subscript[OverTilde["R"], i, j], t]]]

IndexedExpression[i, j]
Table[IndexedExpression[a, b], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]
IndexedExpression[i, j] == 
 Simplify[MatrixForm [
    Table[IndexedExpression[a, b], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]] /. {t 
     SuperStar[t]/(k*Subscript[u, 10]), Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R\>"\), \(~\)]\), 1, 
      1] -> ((a*k*Subscript[u, 10])^2) Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R*\>"\), \(~\)]\), 1, 1], Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R\>"\), \(~\)]\), 1, 
      2] -> ((a*k*Subscript[u, 10])^2) Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R*\>"\), \(~\)]\), 1, 2 ], Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R\>"\), \(~\)]\), 1, 
      3] -> ((a*k*Subscript[u, 10])^2) Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R*\>"\), \(~\)]\), 1, 3],
    Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R\>"\), \(~\)]\), 2, 
      1] -> ((a*k*Subscript[u, 10])^2) Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R*\>"\), \(~\)]\), 2, 1], Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R\>"\), \(~\)]\), 2, 
      2] -> ((a*k*Subscript[u, 10])^2) Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R*\>"\), \(~\)]\), 2, 2 ], Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R\>"\), \(~\)]\), 2, 
      3] -> ((a*k*Subscript[u, 10])^2) Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R*\>"\), \(~\)]\), 2, 3],
     Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R\>"\), \(~\)]\), 3, 
      1] -> ((a*k*Subscript[u, 10])^2) Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R*\>"\), \(~\)]\), 3, 1], Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R\>"\), \(~\)]\), 3, 
      2] -> ((a*k*Subscript[u, 10])^2) Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R*\>"\), \(~\)]\), 3, 2 ], Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R\>"\), \(~\)]\), 3, 
      3] -> ((a*k*Subscript[u, 10])^2) Subscript[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\("\<R*\>"\), \(~\)]\), 3, 3]}]
```

Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Start by making your code more readable: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [your previous question from earlier today](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/300364/27951)?

Comment: 1. In your replacement, the first item in the list of rules, `t *SuperStar[t]/(k*Subscript[u, 10])`, is not a rule. This is an error. 2. You wrapped your expressions by `HoldForm` and `MatrixForm` This prevents  it from being operated. 3. You use strings, such as `"R"`. They cannot be operated with like symbols.  4. It is generally not recommended to use sub- and supescripts, stars and tildas. This influences the way of simplification.